# how does gpio_request deal with the GPIO number to virtual memory address on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory-address, gpio

There is a problem that gpio_request need a GPIO number, but in the kernel it needs a address to deal with the gpio, how does the Linux achieve this?

Alway in the chip spec, such as MSM8x60 or whatever SOC chip Spec, there is a memory map shows which memory area is for GPIO.  But in kernel driver, we use gpio number to access the gpio.

My question is:
1,  Does the memory address in the memory map of chip spec is physical address?
2,  In the kernel, it uses virtual address, how does the kernel convert a gpio number to virtual address?

Thank you!

Kind Regards
Bill Wang

Answer (score 0):

Normally, on the embedded system, there is a address map of the whole address, which address is virtual.

when use the gpio port number, the related GPIO driver or such things can convert the gpio port number to the virtual address, and the MMU will located to the physical address.